# database is not function in react native firebase

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-firebase

this question is not duplicate for firebase.database is not function.
I installed firebase and import  as follow

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native'
import Card from '../components/card'
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'
import database from 'firebase/compat/database'

export default class Home extends Component {

  state = {
    profileIndex: 0,
    profiles: [],
  }

  UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
    firebase.database().ref().child('Users').once('value', (snap) => {
      let profiles = []
      snap.forEach((profile) => {
        const {name, bio, birthday, id} = profile.val()
        profiles.push({name, bio, birthday, id})
      })
      this.setState({profiles})
    })
  }
```

when not import this

```
import database from 'firebase/compat/database'
```

show error as

```
 firebase.daatabase is not function
```

but when import this

```
import database from 'firebase/compat/database'
```

error is gone and work but actually database is not using in code
I want to know the solution for this
How can use this method

```
 firebase.database()
```

what need to import in react native
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> https://rnfirebase.io/database/usage

***Installation***
@react-native-firebase/app
@react-native-firebase/database
***pod install*** 
cd ios/ && pod install && cd ..
import database from '@react-native-firebase/database';